# Access a Network drive from another user from CMD (windows)

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, network-share, batch-file, daemon

I have written PostgreSQL backups scripts that backup all the databases to file.
`pgAgent.exe` (a scheduling daemon) starts the BAT scripts under the local postgres user.

The normal setup is to backup to a local drive and get the backup program to pick up the files but we have a client that would like to backup to a network drive.

I tried running pgAgent and by extension the scripts under the administration user and still did not have any luck. (same user that had the drive mappings)

When i login to the postgres user by running `runas.exe /user:postgres cmd.exe` and type `cd /D Z:` I get the error `The system cannot find the drive specified.`

Now from what i understand, network drives are mapped on a per user session basis. is there a special trick to accessing the network drives from a command prompt?

Comment: If the network share is shared to "everyone" the you can use net use Z: \\SERVERNAME\SHARE

Comment: I made an login for the postgres user and added at the start of the script "net use Z: \\server\share /user:domain\user *password*"

thanks Trozz for pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: no problem mind just adding a vote to the answer i just attached :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
REM Mount Z:\ as the user with permissions; you may need to add the password
net use z: \\server\share /user:domain\user

REM copy things here
REM ...

REM unmount the drive letter
net use z: /d
```

Comment: yea, I suppose that language-specific comments might be helpful...

Answer (score 1):

If the network share is shared to "everyone" the you can use `net use Z: \\SERVERNAME\SHARE`